# Using XSLT to query and pull data from XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xslt

I am trying to use XSLT to solve the following problem but am a bit stuck.

I have an ID of a tool, let's say a hammer. I need to take that ID variable, pass it into an XSLT stylesheet, use the XSLT to match all the Task elements in an XML file containing a tool with that ID .

So in one document (tasks.xml) I have the following (note the `<tool><id>`)

```
<data>
         <DMs>
          <task>
            <DMC>TEST-4BX-AG3-00-00-0000-125B-A</DMC>
            <techName>Fixing fence</techName>
            <infoName>Inserting panels</infoName>
            <tools>
              <tool>
                <id>1</id><qty>1</qty>
              </tool>
              <tool>
                <id>4</id><qty>1</qty>
              </tool>
            </tools>
        </task>
    <task>
            <DMC>TEST-4BX-AG3-00-00-0000-125B-A</DMC>
            <techName>Fixing floor</techName>
            <infoName>Install floorboard</infoName>
            <notes>-</notes>
            <tools>
              <tool>
                <id>89</id><qty>1</qty>
              </tool>
              <tool>
                <id>25</id><qty>2</qty>
              </tool>
            </tools>
        </task>
      </DMs>
     </data>
```

So assuming the hammer's ID is "1", i now need to search the Tasks.xml file and match all Tasks where the hammer is used. Only tasks that have the hammer should be included in the output.

That's the first part of the problem.

I have another file, Tools.xml, which contains all the tool information, as follows:

```
<data>
         <tools>
          <tool id="1">
            <toolName>Hammer</toolName>
            <toolPN>345123</toolPN>
            <toolCage>-</toolCage>
          </tool>
          <tool id="2">
            <toolName>Digital Multimeter Set</toolName>
            <toolPN>Fluke Model No. 89IV</toolPN>
            <toolCage>-</toolCage>
          </tool>
          <tool id="3">
            <toolName>Digital Storage Oscilloscope</toolName>
            <toolPN>Tektronix 3052B</toolPN>
            <toolCage>-</toolCage>
          </tool>
          <tool id="4">
            <toolName>Socket set</toolName>
            <toolPN>737828</toolPN>
            <toolCage>-</toolCage>
          </tool>
       </tools>
    </data>
```

I also need to pull the tool's actual name and details from Tools.XML so the output xml file lists the tools details such as name and part number etc. instead of just an ID.

So what I want is something like this output:

```
<data>
     <DMs>
      <task>
        <DMC>TEST-4BX-AG3-00-00-0000-125B-A</DMC>
        <techName>Fixing fence</techName>
        <infoName>Inserting panels</infoName>
        <tools>
          <tool id="1">
            <toolName>Hammer</toolName>
            <toolPN>345123</toolPN>
            <toolCage>-</toolCage>
          </tool>
          <tool id="4">
            <toolName>Socket set</toolName>
            <toolPN>737828</toolPN>
            <toolCage>-</toolCage>
          </tool>
        </tools>
    </task>
<task>
```

I've been messing around with the XSLT but can't get it right. Everything i try seems to completely remove the tools from the output.

Here's some XSLT i've been playing with using Document() function and XSLT Key, but i'm really just trying to learn XSLT as i go and am getting frustrated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="dataModuleLookupDoc" select="document('C:\TOOLS.xml')"/>

  <xsl:key name="toolIDKey" match="tool" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="task">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$dataModuleLookupDoc"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tools"/>

  <xsl:template match="tool">
    <xsl:variable name="toolID" select="@ID"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$dataModuleLookupDoc">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('toolIDKey',toolID)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `key('toolIDKey',toolID)` you want `key('toolIDKey, $toolID)`. That should find the element in the other document, of course the `<xsl:value-of select="key('toolIDKey, $toolID)"/>` seems too simple an attempt to "pull the tool's actual name and details", either use `xsl:copy-of` if you simply want the element from the other document copied or push it through some templates with `xsl:apply-templates` to transform it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xTools = XDocument.Load(FILENAME2);

            Dictionary<int, Tool> toolsDict = xTools.Descendants("tool")
                .Select(x => new Tool() {
                    id = (int)x.Attribute("id"),
                    name = (string)x.Element("toolName"),
                    pn = (string)x.Element("toolPN"),
                    cage = (string)x.Element("toolCage")
                }).GroupBy(x => x.id, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            XDocument xTasks = XDocument.Load(FILENAME1);
            List<XElement> toolTask = xTasks.Descendants("tool").ToList();
            foreach (XElement tool in toolTask)
            {
                int id = (int)tool.Element("id");
                int qty = (int)tool.Element("qty");
                if(toolsDict.ContainsKey(id))
                {
                    Tool idTool = toolsDict[id];

                    tool.ReplaceWith(new XElement("tool", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("id", id),
                        new XAttribute("qty", qty),
                        new XElement("toolName", idTool.name),
                        new XElement("toolPN", idTool.pn),
                        new XElement("toolCage", idTool.cage)
                    }));
                }

          //                 <toolName>Hammer</toolName>
          //  <toolPN>345123</toolPN>
          //  <toolCage>-</toolCage>
          //</tool>
            }
        }
    }
    public class Tool
    {
        public int id { get;set;}
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string pn { get; set; }
        public string cage { get; set; }
    }
}
```